# what happens to javascript variable after a call to the server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, session

I just began to learn javascript, so here is a silly question :

What happens to a **javascript variable** after a call to the server? Are all the variables wiped out?

I read somewhere that **javascript variable** in ajax can act like **session** or **cookie**. Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the run-time state is reset whenever the browser does a page-load, such as navigating from foo.com/bar to foo.com/baz.  This includes all JavaScript variables, as well as the current DOM.  However, asynchronous calls to the server, such as XHR, do not affect run-time state, and all JavaScript variables will stay.

If you'd like to preserve values between page-loads, you can use **cookies** or **localStorage**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what scope the variable is in. Also, Ajax is different then submitting a page, so your variables are persisted.